# Approaching with Fourier Series for f'(x)=1+xf(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

When I do the product, this ODE doesn't have solution I think that i am doing something wrong.
The exercise is:

Use Fourier Series for approach the solution of the ODE
$$f'(x)=1+xf(x)$$ for $$0<x< \pi$$

With $$f(0)=f(\pi)=0$$

I proposed $$f(x)=a_nSen(nx)$$ as function but i have problems with the products.